# MySQL PHP Querying and Listing as Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, yql, stock

I am trying to make a simple stock exchange application in PHP and have a completely working session-based login system. Now I am having an issue listing the stocks a user has in a table. When I run the exact query that I have made in my PHP code in Navicat, the query returns the desired results, but PHP will not use the information to populate the table. The 0 in current value is a placeholder until I implement the YQL code required to pull stock information. I have a screenshot showing just about everything necessary to view what I am talking about:

[image: screenie]

My PHP code for the query is here:

```
echo "Welcome to your portfolio overview. Here you can view many of your statistics.<br><br><b>Balance:</b> " . $balance . "<br><b>Debt:</b> " . $debt . "<br>";
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `trades` WHERE buyerid=$uid";
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
echo "<table border=2 cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr><td><b>Symbol</b></td><td><b>Purchase Price</b></td><td><b>Current Value</b></td></tr>";
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
{
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row2['identifier'] ."</td><td>" . $row2['purchaseprice'] . "</td><td>" . 0 . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Are you sure your `$uid` variable is correct? Did you display the `$sql2` variable to ensure your query is correct? What does `var_dump($result2)` displays?

Comment: I have tried displaying $uid in the page and it shows that is is 1, which is what I want since zgillis is user id 1. I will try the var_dump($result2).

Comment: it says 'resource(5) of type (mysql result)'

Comment: Ok this means your query is working. In the while() loop what does `var_dump($row2)` returns?

Comment: It is for sure using the correct db because that is how the user id is known to be 1 and how the page knows the name of the user account. It returns: 'bool(false)'

Comment: It shows: string(38) "SELECT * FROM `trades` WHERE buyerid=1"

which seems right.

Comment: Did You do `var_dump($row2);` in loop or outside? It executes at least once as You are getting one row but empty in table.

Comment: in both and it returned the same thing. And that's what I was thinking because the table wouldn't add another row unless it was true at least once.

Comment: Actually, if i replace the variable in the query with 2 or any other number a blank row with 0 still shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an erroneous semicolon after the `while` condition:

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
                                          ^ -- remove this
```

With this semicolon in place, you loop over an empty statement until your resultset is exhausted and then you execute the `echo` statement contained within your braces (with `$row2` now false) irrespective of the `while` loop before.

Answer (score -1):

Line 6:

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
```

must be

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
```